# context api - useEffect doesn't fire on first render - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The `useEffect` doesn't fire on first render, but when I save the file (ctrl+s), the state updates and the results can be seen.

What I want to do is, when I'm in `GameScreen`, I tap on an ICON which takes me to `WalletScreen`, from there I can select some items/gifts (`attachedGifts` - in context) and after finalising I go back to previous screen i.e. `GameScreen` with gifts attached (`attachedGifts!==null`), now again when I tap ICON and go to `WalletScreen` it should show me the gifts that were attached so that I could un-attach them or update selection (this is being done in the `useEffect` below in `WalletScreen`), but the issue is, although my `attachedGifts` state is updating, the `useEffect` in `WalletScreen` does not fire immediately when navigated, when I hit `ctrl+s` to save the file, then I can see my selected/attached gifts in `WalletScreen`.

code:

```js
const Main = () => {
  return (
  <GiftsProvider>
    <Stack.Screen name='WalletScreen' component={WalletScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name='GameScreen' component={GameScreen} />
  </GiftsProvider>
  )
};

const GameScreen = () => {
  const { attachedGifts } = useGifts(); //coming from context - GiftsProvider
  console.log('attached gifts: ', attachedGifts);

  return ...
};

const WalletScreen = () => {
  const { attachedGifts } = useGifts();

  useEffect(() => { // does not fire on initial render, after saving the file, then it works.
        if (attachedGifts !== null) {
            let selectedIndex = -1
            let filteredArray = data.map(val => {
                if (val.id === attachedGifts.id) {
                    selectedIndex = walletData.indexOf(val);
                    setSelectedGiftIndex(selectedIndex);
                    return {
                        ...val,
                        isSelect: val?.isSelect ? !val?.isSelect : true,
                    };
                } else {
                    return { ...val, isSelect: false };
                }
            });
            setData(filteredArray);
        }
    }, [attachedGifts]);

  const attachGiftsToContext = (obj) => {
    dispatch(SET_GIFTS(obj));
    showToast('Gifts attached successfully!');
    navigation?.goBack(); // goes back to GameScreen
  }

  return (
    // somewhere in between
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={attachGiftsToContext}>ATTACH</TouchableOpacity>
  )
};
```

context:

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useReducer } from 'react';

const GiftsReducer = (state: Object | null, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_GIFTS':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const GiftContext = createContext({});

export const GiftsProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const initialGiftState: Object | null = null;

    const [attachedGifts, dispatch] = useReducer(
        GiftsReducer,
        initialGiftState,
    );

    const memoedValue = useMemo(
        () => ({
            attachedGifts,
            dispatch,
        }),
        [attachedGifts],
    );

    return (
        <GiftContext.Provider value={memoedValue}>
            {children}
        </GiftContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default function () {
    return useContext(GiftContext);
}
```

Output of `console.log` in `GameScreen`:

```
attached gifts:  Object {
  "reciptId": "baNlCz6KFVABxYNHAHasd213Fu1",
  "walletId": "KQCqSqC3cowZ987663QJboZ",
}
```

What could possibly be the reason behind this and how do I solve this?

**EDIT**

Added related code here: https://snack.expo.dev/uKfDPpNDr

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> When you call useEffect in your component, this is effectively queuing
> or scheduling an effect to maybe run, after the render is done.
>
> After rendering finishes, useEffect will check the list of dependency
> values against the values from the last render, and will call your
> effect function if any one of them has changed.

You might want to take a different approach to this.
There is not much info, but I can try to suggest to put it into render, so it might look like this

```
const filterAttachedGifts = useMemo(() => ...your function from useEffect... , [attachedGitfs])
```

Some where in render you use "data" variable to render attached gifts, instead, put filterAttachedGifts function there.

Or run this function in component body and then render the result.

```
const filteredAttachedGifts = filterAttachedGifts()
```

It would run on first render and also would change on each attachedGifts change.

If this approach doesn't seems like something that you expected, please, provide more code and details

**UPDATED**

I assume that the problem is that your wallet receive attachedGifts on first render, and after it, useEffect check if that value was changed, and it doesn't, so it wouldn't run a function.

You can try to move your function from useEffect into external function and use that function in 2 places, in useEffect and in wallet state as a default value

feel free to pick up a better name instead of "getUpdatedArray"

```
const getUpdatedArray = () => {
    const updatedArray = [...walletData];
    if (attachedGifts !== null) {
        let selectedIndex = -1
        updatedArray = updatedArray.map((val: IWalletListDT) => {
            if (val?.walletId === attachedGifts?.walletIds) {
                selectedIndex = walletData.indexOf(val);
                setSelectedGiftIndex(selectedIndex);
                setPurchaseDetailDialog(val);
                return {
                    ...val,
                    isSelect: val?.isSelect ? !val?.isSelect : true,
                };
            } else {
                return { ...val, isSelect: false };
            }
        });
    }    
    return updatedArray;
}
```

Then use it here

```
const [walletData, setWalletData] = useState(getUpdatedArray());
```

and in your useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    setWalletData(getUpdatedArray());
}, [attachedGifts]);
```

That update should cover the data on first render. That might be not the best solution, but it might help you. Better solution require more code\time etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I have added more code here, if you'd like please check this and let me know if it helped to understand more, https://snack.expo.dev/uKfDPpNDr

Comment: I will update my answer

Comment: I think, as I navigated so the `WalletScreen` is not `unmounted` so I think that is why the `useEffect` didn't run because it never unmounted... so i might need to unmount the `WalletScreen` whenever I navigate, or use `useFocusEffect` but I did try `useFocusEffect` and it is still the same....

Comment: In case if WalletScreen is not unmounted, you wouldn't have this issue, because when you update attachedGifts, it would be instantly handled by your useEffect. So since that doesn't happen I assume that WalletSceen is unmounted on leave